Regarding POSIX ERE's new ? repetition modifier
The 2024 version of POSIX specifies the ? repetition modifier. In the published document, it's specified that the ? modifier changes the behavior of its immediately preceeding repetition from matching the left-most longest match to left-most shortest match. A REG_MINIMAL flag had also been added to the C interface to alter the overall behavior of an ERE match. The original proposals can be found at here and subsequently amended here.
This question seeks clarification on several aspects:

The ? applies to a repetition, but how does it achieve the "shortest" match? For example given (a.+b)+?, does the behavior for the + inside the parentheses accommodate for the outer +?

For an overall match with groupings/capture/subpattern (correct my terminology if you spot mistake(s)), it is said:

... each subpattern, from left to right, shall match the longest possible string ...

how does that rule apply to ones modified with the new ? repetition modifier? Since ? applies to repetition, it shouldn't matter for the length of the parenthesized subpattern itself/proper. Can someone confirm this?


What would be useful examples to demonstrate this?
I seek clarification on its use with parentheses-nested grouping of greedy/lazy quantifiers, whereas What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions? just focuses on the greediness/laziness concept itself, as well as relationship between partial and overall matches.

This is just about greedy vs. lazy quantifiers.

You say it yourself: "IMMEDIATE preceding  repetition", that is the + outside the whole group. If you want the inside to follow the same rule, you need to add a ? inside the group.

It appears to be some kind of unintentional underspecification. I've reported it to Austin Group.

x{1,3} matches the same as xxx|xx|x
x{1,3}? matches the same as x|xx|xxx
(wx+y){1,3} matches the same as wx+ywx+ywx+y|wx+ywx+y|wx+y
(wx+y){1,3}? matches the same as wx+y|wx+ywx+y|wx+ywx+ywx+y
x+ matches the same as x{1,} and matches the same as x{1,999999999999999999}
Warning: It is not advisable to use the equivalent expansions of the quantifiers. They are shown here for pedagogical purposes only.
As can be clearly deduced from these exercises showing the trivial expansion of quantifiers, a modifier ? written after a quantifier affects exclusively that quantifier and does not affect quantifiers within the quantified group -when the quantifier is applied to a group-.

This doesn't answer his specific questions.  In particular, he asked about (a.+b)+?.

The last paragraph, added by editing, answers not only the specific questions and the particular example but also the more general case about this topic.

The answer still focuses on examples he didn't ask about and don't address (a.+b)+? (or even +?), which he did ask about.  The bigger issue is that the answer makes assertions about equivalent regexes, but doesn't back them up.  It's a question about a new standard, but there are no citations to the standard or summaries of it.  There's no link to running examples (for POSIX 2024 regexes), etc (as an alternative to citing the standard).

+ is just one of several quantifiers, but the ? modifier applies to all of them equally: +?, *?, ??, {1,3}?. But the advantage of analyzing the case {1,3}? is that it is very easy to study its trivial expansion and reach ultimate conclusions. It is an interesting study strategy, because it solves many questions at once without the need to study each particular case. I am very sorry that this approach is not well received or appreciated here. I think that giving a separate answer for each specific quantifier and for each regex "flavor" when a general answer fits is nonsense.

"This is just about greedy vs. lazy quantifiers". –Wiktor Stribiżew

That is, a generic topic. -

